# Laravel artisan route list database connection error

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I'm using Laravel 5 and when I am running `php artisan route:list`, it always gives me an error of **SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'homestead'@'localhost' (using password: YES)**. This shouldn't be because my application will not be connecting to any database since it will be a static website.

I tried removing the variables on the .env file:

```
DB_HOST=localhost
DB_DATABASE=homestead
DB_USERNAME=homestead
DB_PASSWORD=secret
```

Just still gives me errors. It seems like it is still connecting to the database wherein it shouldn't make any database connection.

Comment: have you checked that your MySQL server is started or not? and your user homestead have access to your homestead database and your password is correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was experiencing the same issues when I upgraded my Laravel installer from v1.1 to v1.2.

It appears that the routes.php file by default is adding the Authentication route:

```
Route::controllers([
    'auth' => 'Auth\AuthController',
    'password' => 'Auth\PasswordController',
]);
```

This causes to display an error message to what you were describing:

```
$ php artisan route:list

  [PDOException]                                                                          
  SQLSTATE[28000] [1045] Access denied for user 'forge'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
```

I resolved this by removing the scaffolding included within Laravel by executing the following command:

```
$ php artisan fresh
```

Or by simply deleting the Auth route within the file itself.

You should now be able to run: `php artisan route:list`

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you so much!! It works now! Just curious to know, what does the command `php artisan fresh` do? What file(s) did it remove or edit? What does "Scaffolding" mean? Thanks again Koufax!

Comment: The way that I have come to understand scaffolding is how an application interacts with a database for basic CRUD operations.  I am not entirely sure how Laravel implements this process.

Edit:  You can read more about scaffolding here:  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scaffold_%28programming%29

As for the `php artisan fresh` command, only the routes.php file seems to be affected.  I copied a fresh Laravel project directory, ran a diff between both of those files after executing `php artisan fresh` and the only file that stood out in the diff results was the routes.php file.

Comment: I do notice that the Auth folder is removed too. I am assuming that the fresh command removes samples from the laravel installation. If im not mistaken, I think it makes your laravel installation "fresh", from the word itself.

Comment: Looks like it does.  I am not sure why they would even add this content in the first place.  Thanks for the heads up.

Comment: I think it is for demo purposes. But it would be better if they state it in the documentation to type in the `fresh` command if they want a clean install.

Comment: They do, it's right here under "Scaffolding" http://laravel.com/docs/5.0#install-laravel

Answer (score 0):

This might be the problem of localhost. Do check your WAMP, MAMP, LAMP and XAMP MySql server if you are using any of them.

Comment: this looks more like a comment then answer

Answer (score 0):

This have solve my problem:

It looks like artisan might be working in the wrong environment. Run "`php artisan tinker`", then "`App::environment();`" to see which environment Artisan is running in. If it is something other than production, you need to create a folder with that environments name within your app/config folder, and put a copy of the "database.php" file in it.

After That if you are not doing any DB related task it will not access DB.

I found answer [here](http://laravel.io/forum/07-02-2014-sqlstatehy000-1044-access-denied-for-user-localhost-to-database-forge?page=1)

Alternatively You can run following command to resolve this issue:

```
php artisan migrate:install --env="local"
```

After this run you command:

```
php artisan route:list
```

Enjoy.

Comment: When I ran `App::environment();`, it returns local. Isn't the config folder in Laravel 5 is on the root of laravel installation? Also, it shouldn't connect to the database since I am not making any connection and should NOT make any connection since I am just building a static website where NO database will be used. Btw, this is just a fresh installation of Laravel 5.0.13

Comment: You can run the alternative solution, then I guess all of your commands will run properly.

Comment: It is still giving me the `SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'homestead'@'localhost' (using password: YES)` error when running `php artisan migrate:install --env="local"`